# ValueObject pattern in django models

Tags: python, django, design-patterns, django-models, value-objects

Currently I want to use the Value Object Pattern in my django project. I have a class `Price` like this:

```
class Price(object):
    def __init__(self, value, currency):
       self.value = value
       self.currency = currency
```

And now I want to use this class in a normal model. The question is simple, how should I use it in the model? What type of field?

My most important requirement is, that I can access the price directly on an instance of the model. So that I could write something like this:

```
item.price.in(Currency.EURO)
```

So I don't need to call some methods to invoke for example deserialization, if I store the price as JSON in the database.

Thanks for your help!

**Edit**

Because the question was not clear enough, I created a more detailed description:

I have a normal python class `Price` (not a django model!)

```
class Price(object):
    def __init__(self, value, currency):
       self.value = value
       self.currency = currency
```

And then I have a django model `Item`.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # other not necessary fields
```

Now I want to have a `price` in `Item` that I could write something like `item.price.in(DOLLAR)` or `item.price.in(EURO)`. But I **don’t** want to create two fields in `Item` like this:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price_value = models.FloatField()
    price_currency = models.IntegerField(choices=Currency.CHOICES)
```

I also **don’t** want to have a `ForeignKey` to `Price` that I need to make the class `Price` a subclass of `models.Model`.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.ForeignKey(Price)
```

So the question is, how can I store a `Price` (not a django model) in the `Item` (django model)?

Comment: Aren't you essentially describing a many to many relationship between item and Currency with Price as the middle table with value and Currency the foreign keys?

Comment: Could also be a possibility, but I wanted to try it out without an own model.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd better define `value` and `currency` as fields for the model, then you could have method of the model to give you the price:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    CURRENCIES = Choices(                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
        ('USD', 'US Dollars'),                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        ('EUR', 'Euro'),                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
        ('GBP', 'British Pound'),                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
        ('AUD', 'Australian Dollar'))

    value = fields.DecimalField()
    currency = fields.CharField(max_length=4, choices=CURRENCIES)

    def price_convertion(self, new_currency):
        # take self.value and self.currency and convert it
        # according to new_currency
```

Or you could make currency itself a model if you want to be really flexible, but the class function is the same:

```
class Currency(Model):
    name = fields.CharField(max_length=4)

class MyModel(Model):
    currency = fields.ForeignKey(Currency)
```

Comment: Yes, maybe thats a better way. But apart from how good it is, how could you store an object in a django model, without creating an own model for it? Now I'm more focused on that question. But also thank you for your first answer ;)

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question `how could you store an object in django model without creating its own model`. Which part of the code are you referring to?

Comment: I have edited the question, that it's (hopefully) understandable.

Comment: I wonder if ValueObjects are just not the "Python/Django way".